# Как сделать внешнюю ссылку на страницу, которая загружается на сайте через jquery .load?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ссылки

На сайте страницы page1.php, page2.php и т.д. загружаются на страницу index.php с помощью jquery load. Как можно сделать, чтобы были рабочими ссылки типа mysite.com/page1?

Answer (score 0):

```
var file = 'page2.php';

    $('div').load(file, '', function(data){
        $(this).after('<a href='+file+'>'+file+'</a>')
    })
```